# Find all teams whose defenders averaged more than 150 passes. Return the average number of passes by defenders, in descending order of average passes

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following query for the question but it's not giving any output or error.

[ "Return the team and
average number of passes by defenders, in descending order of average passes" this is what I want as ouput

```
select team, avg(passes) from player where position = 'defender' and avg(passes)>150 order by avg(passes)
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obosQ.png)

Comment: Study the usage of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses - you will need them here.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL to achieve your desired idea.

```
SELECT
    team,
    AVG(passes) AS 'avg'
FROM
    player
WHERE
    POSITION = 'defender'
GROUP BY
    `team`
HAVING
    AVG(passes) > 150
ORDER BY
    AVG(passes) DESC
```